# Sending message from Android application to Azure IoT Hub device

Tags: android, azure, iot

I'm currently using Azure for a project. In this project I hava a Android Application and a IoT(NodeMCU 1.0) and I have found a way to send messages from the IoT Device to my android application using Azure, but now I have to send data from the Android application to the IoT device. the device is using IoT Hub to send information to Azure.

Comment: How did you send data from mobile app to cloud? Any link?

Answer (score 0):

You could use IoT REST API to send a command to device from your android application. Refer https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1113447/Azure-IOT-Hub-REST-API for more details.

Another reference: https://microsoft.github.io/techcasestudies/iot/2016/11/29/Agatsa.html

Comment: I'm trying to use the solution of the first link, but I'm getting an error 400 while making a post request using Volley library for android/java.

Comment: And in this solution I can send messages from the Android and receive cloud to Device messages, but I want to know how to make Android send a messa to another IoT device

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, based on my understanding, I think you want to send data from Android app to IoT device via the way of sending cloud-to-device messages of Azure IoTHub. You need to do two steps for implementing the needs.

First of all, there are two ways to implement for sending a cloud-to-device message to IoTHub.

1. Directly sending data from Android App to IoTHub, you can refer to the section [`Send a cloud-to-device message`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-java-java-c2d#send-a-cloud-to-device-message) of the offical tutorial for Java to do it, but I think it's not a good idea to do it between Android and IoTHub that considering the concurrency requests for IoTHub come from android devices installed your app.
2. So per my experience, the better way is that create a Mobile App for Node.js which will handle the request from Android devices and forward the data to IoTHub via [`Send a cloud-to-device message` using Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-node-node-c2d).

Then, you can try to call the REST API [Receive Device Bound Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/httpruntime#HttpRuntime_ReceiveDeviceBoundNotification) using eLua or Arduino ino code at regular intervals on IoT devices to receive the c2d message, like the code in the section [`Receive messages in the simulated device app`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-node-node-c2d#receive-messages-in-the-simulated-device-app).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to use that solution.

Comment: If I use this Node.js solution I would need to have it running on another server all the time, right? Isn't there a way to use Azure App Functions to do this, and this funtion receives the request from the Android App and then it sends the command to a IoT Hub Device?

Comment: @MarcosFelipe Right. Also, you can use Azure Functions with IoTHub SDK for Node.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to send data from Android device to Azure IoT Hub then please follow following Microsoft Articles

1. [Quickstart: Control a device connected to an IoT hub (Android)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-control-device-android)
2. [Quickstart: Send IoT telemetry from an Android device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-send-telemetry-android)